# AS3 Finding out what button was clicked from looped dynamically added buttons

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

This is driving me insane now.

I have a loop that creates buttons. Each button stays on the screen, but scrolls off, meaning there are at any one time upto 4 buttons on the screen. There are a total of 241 buttons.

It is to my understanding that using an array will allow me to access these buttons later, and that is great, but I can not find a way for it to tell me exactly which button was clicked.

Am I missing something very simple here?

```
if (canAdd == true)
        {
            canAdd = false;
            while (curName < nextName)
            {
                var names:namez = new namez();
                names.ID = curName;
                names.name = "ID"+(curName);
                mcArray[curName] = names;
                names.t2.dtf_txt.text = getNames[curName];
                names.y = -28;
                spinner.addChild(names);
                if (curName < nextName)
                {
                    curName = nextName;
                    trace("curName updated to "+curName);
                }
            }
            mcArray[curName - 1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkMe);
        }

        timer.start();

    }

    public function checkMe(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        trace("you clicked " + e.target.name);
        //trace("clicked: "+e.target.ID)
        //var names:namez = e.target as namez;
        //trace("clicked" + names.ID);
        //trace("clicked"+namez.ID);
    }
}
```

What exactly should be in checkMe?

As you can see I have tried all sorts - The namez class even has an ID internal variable within it, but calling that still just gives an error.

Comment: What does that line output when you click a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [e.currentTarget](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) instead of e.target